# How switch to default keyboard on Ubuntu (Logitech K-380)

Tags: keyboard, logitech

I connect my keyboard Logitech K-380 on my computer (Ubuntu 18). When I want refresh my navigator, I have to do fn+F5... I just want to do F5.

How switch my keyboard to default ?

Logitech option software do not exist on Linux, just for Mac and Windows ..

*https://support.logitech.fr/fr_fr/software/options*

Thank's community

Comment: For linux , please follow instruction [link](https://github.com/jergusg/k380-function-keys-conf) .
I've test with ubuntu 16.04 and it's working perfectly .

Comment: solaar installed via pip worked for me with the "K400 Plus" model